# Unticked accepted answer

Tags: feature-request, accepted-answer

In which cases can the answer that was marked as "accepted" be canceled?

It's clear that by spending hours you could prepare "shiny, sparkling, and flamboyant answer" (and, possibly, by grabbing all right answers on the page) that do not help to resolve the issue in the meantime, but is it a matter to switch acceptance? Won't it better to activate "timeout" for a possibility to change the right answer (in the same way how it was done for comments)?

Comment: Why? The accepted answer is supposed to be the answer that helps the OP the most. The one the op found truly answered his question. Why shouldn't they be allowed to switch if a better one comes along?

Comment: Regular votes timeout in an effort to curb malicious voting behavior. A user who posts a question can't game anything by un-accepting an answer (AFAIK).

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is up to the OP. For example OP posted a code with some small mistakes and someone answered just by correcting the code without any explanation.

Then OP accepted it.

After 1/2 days, another person made a detailed answer explaining everything, then the new answer is of good quality and it clearly say why don't use such practise/ what are all the things to care, etc. Then it should be the accepted answer.

Let's take another scenario

A person asked a question 1 year ago and got a good answer. But now the technology is deprecated and alternative one is live. Then someone answered with the new technology. Then at present, the new one will be helpful and it will be the accepted answer.

The accepted answer not only help the OP but also the community and future visitors.

So, the accepted answer can be changed whenever necessary.